# Scapy getlayer options

Tags: python-2.7, scapy, pcap

This is my code:

```
from scapy.all import *

packets = rdpcap('secret.pcap')

packet_join = []

for packet in packets:
    if packet.haslayer('TCP'):
        raw_data = packet.getlayer(Raw)
        packet_join.append(raw_data)
```

I only found the `getlayer(Raw)` from some googling.

My question is, is there a list of the layers I can use for `getlayer` somewhere? Or more detailed documentation on its use? I couldn't find much in the Scapy documentation.

I know you can also use things like `getlayer(TCP)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use any Scapy layer as attribute of `.getlayer()` and `.haslayer()`. You can list the loaded layers by using `ls()`.

By the way, it's better to write `TCP in x` rather than `x.haslayer(TCP)` and `x[Raw]` rather than `x.getlayer(Raw)`.

Answer (score 0):

```
for packet in scapy_cap:
    # code = scapy.layers.http.HTTPResponse.(packet)
    if IP in packet:
        ip_src=packet[IP].src
        #save the ip in set
        SRC_IP.update()
        ip_dst=packet[IP].dst
        #save the ip in set
        DST_IP.update()
        if packet.haslayer(DNS) and packet.getlayer(DNS).qr == 0:
            print(str(ip_src)+ " -> " + str(ip_dst) + " : "+ "(" + str(packet.getlayer(DNS).qd.qname)+ ")")
```

I am currently working with scapy. Here I am using scapy layer option to get the DNS domain name form the pcap file.